# configuration api_fields for DataObject on Silverstripe 4 via colymba/silverstripe-restfulapi

Tags: api, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I try the [colymba/silverstripe-restfulapi](https://github.com/colymba/silverstripe-restfulapi) for my project i received the Api for my [blog](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog) but i need more data in Categories & FeaturedImage.
my categories & featuredimage:

```
"FeaturedImage": 13,
"Categories": [
1
],
"Tags": [
2
],
```

what i need is the Address link & title of the FeaturedImage & Categories , something like this:

```
"FeaturedImage": 
{"ID": 13, 
"Link": "sample/link/address"}
"Categories": [
{"ID": 1,
 "Link": "sample/link/address", 
"Title": "SampleTitle"}
],
```

I read [these docs](https://github.com/colymba/silverstripe-restfulapi/blob/master/doc/DefaultSerializer.md) and change my configuration for this export but i have some error or nothings to happen
What is the correct configuration for this?